# Best way to increase hibernate insertion performance with high volume of data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I'm dealing with a web application which uses Hibernate to handle the object-relational impedance mismatch.
I need to insert nearly 1 million of tuples in a MySQL database as fast as possible.
The data I need to insert contains a field which is auto generated from the database, so I set up my POJO class as follows:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Datum {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Basic(optional = false)
private Integer idDatum;

private Long timestamp;
private Float temperature;
private Float pressure;
private Float humidity;
private Float rain;
private Float windModule;
private String windDirection;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idStation")
private Station station;

public Datum() {}

public Datum(Long timestamp, Float temperature, Float pressure, Float humidity, Float rain, Float windModule, String windDirection) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.temperature = temperature;
    this.pressure = pressure;
    this.humidity = humidity;
    this.rain = rain;
    this.windModule = windModule;
    this.windDirection = windDirection;
}

// getter and setter not reported for brevity

}
```

The above class is `abstract` because it specializes in multiple classes, here is an example of one specialization:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DatumCountry")
public class DatumCountry extends Datum {

private Float dewPoint;

public DatumCountry() {}

public DatumCountry(Long timestamp, Float temperature, Float pressure, Float humidity, Float rain, Float windModule, String windDirection, Float dewPoint) {
    super(timestamp,temperature,pressure,humidity,rain,windModule,windDirection);
    this.dewPoint = dewPoint;
}

// getter and setter not reported for brevity

}
```

I'm using batches to insert tuples in the database, so the code for the insertion is:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
int i = 0;
Integer batchSize = Integer.parseInt(new Configuration().configure().getProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"));
for (Object datum : data) {
     i++;
     session.persist(datum);
     if (i % batchSize == 0) {
         session.flush();
         session.clear();
     }
}
try {
    tr.commit();
} catch (RollbackException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    tr.rollback();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

and `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` is set to 50.

Executing the above code, in the server log I get for 50 times the following:

```
Hibernate: select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where tbl.sequence_name=? for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and sequence_name=?
```

and then, for 50 times I get:

```
Hibernate: insert into DatumCountry (humidity, pressure, rain, idStation, temperature, timestamp, windDirection, windModule, dewPoint, idDatum) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And it keeps doing this until all the tuples have been inserted.

Clearly, everything works fine, but the problem is that it is **TOO SLOW** (an insertion of 1 million tuples takes up to half an hour).

My guess is that since the id is auto generated by database, the select and update are made in order to keep synchronized hibernate and the database itself, but performing these two query lead to a big loss of performance.

At this point, my question is: is there any way to perform insertion of high volume of data through Hibernate **without** performing these two query (thus improving performance)?

**EDIT:**

The problem is not related to the machine in which my application is running. I have found [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/) which explains my problem and, apparently, how to solve it.

Modifying the code as shown in that article, an exception is raised with root cause `org.hibernate.MappingException: Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for: Model.DatumCountry`.

It seems that there are some problems with the auto generation of the id and the inheritance structure of the code...

Comment: What does `new Configuration().configure()` do, read from disk? Also isn't batch size handled by hibernate itself? Have you tried setting batch size higher? Did that go faster?

Comment: The code you have reported read from the hibernate configuration file (hibernate.cfg.xml), therefore it reads from disk. I don't know if batch size is handled by hibernate itself, I have set it in the hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: Can you try removing your own implementation of batch-size, it appears you're reading from disk every loop (so 1 million times reading a file from disk for 1 million tuples) which might be part of your performance issue. Or atleast determine what the configured batch-size is outside your loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed my code, now the batch size is determined outside the loop. The performance seems to be very slightly improved, but still this is not enough... I edited my question with the new version of the code.

Comment: I'd still try removing your own implementation and let hibernate handle it, see how that performs.

Comment: Disabling the query logging will probably also increase performance.

Comment: Yes, I can do what you both have said, but I think they are all workaround... In my opinion the problem resides in the fact that Hibernate is performing a select and then an update **for each** insert query. This means that for 1 million tuples, I will hit the db 3 millions times... Avoiding these two queries (select and update) might improve performance a lot.

Comment: Could you post on pastebin.com and share the links, from root login, MySQL Command Prompt,  TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE hibernate_sequences: B) SHOW CREATE TABLE DatumCountry;  C) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; D) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; E) RAM available on your server, F) CORES, G) Any SSD or NVME storage?

Comment: This is the output of what @WilsonHauck has asked:
[A](https://pastebin.com/vChj7pW6), [B](https://pastebin.com/MzwTugHq), [C](https://pastebin.com/wdPpipqK), [D](https://pastebin.com/6qfJZXiv). As regards questions E, F and G: I am using as a server my laptop, which has 16 gb ram, 6 cores with a SSD storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days I managed to find an optimal solution for my problem. 
I will post here how I solved the problem in order to avoid painful hours to other people in the future.

It seems that ids which are auto generated from the database (`auto-increment` of `MySQL`, in my case) and Hibernate don't really get along if the main goal is to obtain high performance.

For this reason I have decided to reconsider the database structure and change the primary key of the `DatumCountry` table from something which can be known by Hibernate only performing a query against the db, to something which can be known by Hibernate without hitting the database. In my case `timestamp` and `idStation`were sufficient to uniquely identify a tuple.

Once this optimization was done, the performance of my application increased a lot, passing **from more than half an hour (it was actually almost one hour) to more or less 63 seconds** for 1 million tuples. This results has been obtained also thanks batch inserts.

Thanks anyway to anybody who has tried to help me.

Comment: Use of datatype of 'timestamp' guarantees software FAILURE after January 19, 2038.   You will be trying to store a DATE outside the available RANGE of dates.  I realize 2038 is more than 15 years out.  Will your software be 'mothballed'/retired/abandoned before then?

Answer (score 0):

If performance is critical for your application, you have to provide some custom implementations to hibernate to control things.

ex:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
                name = "yourname",
                strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator",
                parameters =
                {
                  @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                  @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "500"),
                  @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.PooledOptimizer"),
                  @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "segment_value", value = "yourEntityName")
                }
              )
```

evaluate weather you need your own hi low generator algorithm or you may use inbuilt generator TableGenerator.
evaluate weather you need your own id optimizer or you may use PooledOptimizer.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely DatumCountry is maintaining an UNNECESSARY Foreign Key, eating CPU and storage according to the SHoW CREATE TABLE information.

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G  # from 8M for 1/2 of available RAM
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 percent to expedite ADD rows
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to enable higher IOPS on SSD
thread_cache_size=20  # from 10 to avoid thread creation delays
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 64K to reduce Handler_read_next RPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=20000  # from 150000 (15 seconds) to 2 seconds when busy
innodb_open_files=2000  # from 300 should always match table_open_cache
max_connect_errors=10  # from 100 why give a hacker/cracker 100 opportunities
max_heap_table_size=75M  # from 16M to match tmp_table_size
```

Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile where we offer downloadable FREE Utility Scripts, additional suggestions and contact info.

Comment: @Fancesco Alongi  Were these suggestions of any value to you? Not tried or positive/negative/no difference in response time?